# Upload Files in Yii2 (word, pdf, excel)?

Tags: yii2

Hy, i can't upload files in yii2. 
When i try to upload files, it is not uploaded on server, also can't past validation.

print_r($_FILES, true) - is empty.
In debuger don't have errors.

Here is my code:

**Model**:

```
class Model extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
 public $files;
 public function rules()
 {
 return [
 [['files'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'doc, docx', 
 'maxFiles' => 4],
 }
}

    public function uploadFiles(){
        if($this->validate()){
            foreach($this->files as $file){ 
                $path = 'upload/docs/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
                $file->saveAs($path);
                @unlink($path);
            }
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Controller**:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Model();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

            $model->files = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'files');
            $model->uploadFiles();

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
```

**View**:

```
_form.php
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],
]); ?>

<?php echo $form->field($model, 'files[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true]) ?>
```

Comment: its been some time you have been here on SO but you still need to add a description to your post we don't know what validation error do you receive when uploading files and also the directory you are trying to upload the file `$model->upload()` should be added

Comment: Hi @MuhammadOmerAslam, i maked necessary modifications.

Comment: what action are called when you submit the form? create.php?

Comment: actionCreate and actionUpdate

Comment: Why you're calling `@unlink($path);` after saving image (it will delete it)? Why you're saving images only after successful `save()` call?

Comment: i get code of function upload() from another project, where was used costa-rico/yii2-widget, wich have his own behaviors. 
You are right, the problem is in this code: @unlink($path); THANKS